# How do I remove the border from a Bokeh GMap plot?

Tags: google-maps, bokeh

Anytime I attempt to plot a GMapPlot in Bokeh I get a huge border around the map itself. Can this be removed? I can't seem to find the option for doing so.

Here is a visual example of what I mean:

[image]

MWE:

```python
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.models import GMapPlot, GMapOptions, DataRange1d, ColumnDataSource, Circle, PanTool, HoverTool

map_options = GMapOptions(lat=40.7484, lng=-73.9857, map_type = "terrain", zoom=10)

GMap = GMapPlot(x_range = DataRange1d(), y_range = DataRange1d(), map_options = map_options , title = "Eneumerate",
            plot_width=800, plot_height=300)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have confirmed this as a bug in Bokeh issues: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/4350.

I'm not sure of the cause yet - my best guess is a change in the GoogleMaps API.